# How can I make error message appear on right side of input box in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, styles

[image: **As shown below, I would like to see error messages appear on right side rather than at the bottom of "By" input element**]

As shown below, I would like to see error messages appear on right side rather than at the bottom of "By" input element.

```
   <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label class="control-label" for="crossValidationFolds">By</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            <input required 
                            id="crossValidationFolds"
                            name="crossValidationFolds" 
                            type="number"
                            class="form-control" 
                            #crossValidationFolds="ngModel" 
                            pattern="^(1[0-2]|[1-9])"
                            [(ngModel)]="crossValidationFoldsValue"
                            [ngClass]="crossValidationFolds.touched && crossValidationFolds.invalid?'is-invalid': crossValidationFolds.valid? '':''"
                           />


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 invalid-feedback" *ngIf="crossValidationFolds.touched && crossValidationFolds.invalid">


                        By Value is invalid

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: I did attempt. I can't post the code right now as I'm traveling.. will come back with code shortly. If u get working code pls let me know. Thank you in advance

Comment: @paulie-d - upadated the question with code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```css
#crossValidationFolds {
  float: left;
}

.col-md-4.invalid-feedback {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="crossValidationFolds">By</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <input required id="crossValidationFolds" name="crossValidationFolds" type="number" class="form-control" #crossValidationFolds="ngModel" pattern="^(1[0-2]|[1-9])" [(ngModel)]="crossValidationFoldsValue" [ngClass]="crossValidationFolds.touched && crossValidationFolds.invalid?'is-invalid': crossValidationFolds.valid? '':''"
    />


  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 invalid-feedback" *ngIf="crossValidationFolds.touched && crossValidationFolds.invalid">


    By Value is invalid

  </div>

</div>
```